# DCOM CoCreateInstanceEx failing

Tags: .net, dcom

im writing opc client. which create instance of com server on remote server.
at first: all setting on remote server are right. i tested 5 opc-example clients, and they are working fine.
but when i use cocreateinstance from my code it fails, with access denied.
i think its because of:

```
COAUTHINFO coauthinfo = new COAUTHINFO();
        coauthinfo.dwAuthnSvc = 0;
        coauthinfo.dwAuthzSvc = 0;
        coauthinfo.pwszServerPrincName = IntPtr.Zero;
        coauthinfo.dwAuthnLevel = 0;
        coauthinfo.dwImpersonationLevel = 1;
        coauthinfo.pAuthIdentityData = IntPtr.Zero;
        coauthinfo.dwCapabilities = 0;
```

which constants must i write here, to get anonyoumus access. i mean invoke dcom only by using guid of com server, and name of remote server?